# Mirror Radiobutton on another tab

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

In a winform application
On a TabControl "Camera" I got 2 radiobuttons for choises of which camera method to activate.
On another Tab "Callibration" i want to have these options again.
And they should always be the same.

The problem though is

That on TabLoad of callibration i can check if the option on "Camera" is checked. But as soon as i try to check the similar checkbox on the calibration tab, then i trigger the selection event

How can i mirror 2 radio buttons over two tabs ?.

Comment: Unbind the Changed event from your second radio button.

Comment: It would be more convenient (and simple, [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is really cool ^^ ) to have the radio buttons only once, outside of the TabControl, instead of duplicating them for no additional value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular databinding between the two

```
radioButton1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", radioButton2, "Checked", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6y3aby2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Great, I never had to use something like this before, is this used in other areas as well ?, Databindings.Add seams well constructed design.

Comment: If you want to add this capability to a custom class you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As discussed, manually bind and un-bind the changed event from the 2nd radio button before you set its checked value.

the below works for me locally.

In the tab control change event, get hold of the tab selected and unbind accordingly.

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var selectedTab = ((TabControl)sender).SelectedTab.Name;

      if (selectedTab == "Callibration")
      {
           rdCallibrationCameraMethod.CheckedChanged -= rdCallibrationCameraMethod_CheckedChanged;
           rdCallibrationCameraMethod.Checked = rdCameraMethod.Checked;
         }
      }
```

You can then re-bind the changed event if needed.

```
rdCallibrationCameraMethod.CheckedChanged += rdCallibrationCameraMethod_CheckedChanged;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: yes it came to mind, but i kinda rejected to code it  that way, as i hoped there would be a better aprouch, which i see in the solution provided by miguelmpn

Comment: @user3800527 - that's fine. I've not done winforms for a few years now anyway. Cheers